# How to define names hierarchy in ETW EventSource?

Tags: c#, etw, etw-eventsource, perfview

In my project I use System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource like this:

```
namespace kafka4net.Tracing
{
    [EventSource(Name = "kafka4net")]
    public class ConnectionTrace : EventSource
    {
        public static ConnectionTrace Log = new ConnectionTrace();

        public void Connecting(string host, int port)
        {
            Log.WriteEvent(1, host, port);
        }

        public void Connected(string host, int port)
        {
            Log.WriteEvent(2, host, port);
        }
    }
}
```

I use PerfView with dynamic provider feature by defining "*kafka4net" in "Additional Providers" field. This resolves provider by its name. Works just fine. With one exception. Events I see are of kafka4net/Connecting whereas I would like to see kafka4net/ConnectionTrace/Connecting.

Generally speaking, I want event to be product/subsystem/event. I can see some system components have this structure, for example "Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime/GC/Start".

I tried to put [EventSource(Name = "kafka4net-Connection")], but than I can not use it as dynamic event in PerfView because I would have to enumerate all my subsystems like "kafka4net-Connection, kafka4net-Fetcher", etc. And this is no go.

EventSource has Name property which can be top-level "product" and function name is used as lowest-level in the event name hierarchy. How do I stick in a middle element "subsystem" in event name hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can't be done because `ProviderName/Event/OpCode` is the convention to show Events in PerfView.

`Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime/GC/Start` also follows this. `Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime is` the provider, `GC` is the Event and `Start` is the OpCode.

You can use Tasks to get a better output:

```
public class Tasks
{
    public const EventTask Connect = (EventTask)0x1;
}

[EventSource(Name = "kafka4net")]
public sealed class ConnectionTrace : EventSource
{
    public static ConnectionTrace Log = new ConnectionTrace();

    [Event(1, Task = Tasks.Connect, Opcode = EventOpcode.Start)]
    public void Connecting(string host, int port)
    {
        if (Log.IsEnabled())
        {
            Log.WriteEvent(1, host, port);
        }
    }

    [Event(2, Task = Tasks.Connect, Opcode = EventOpcode.Stop)]
    public void Connected(string host, int port)
    {
        if (Log.IsEnabled())
        {
            Log.WriteEvent(2, host, port);
        }
    }
}
```

Here you have a better output in PerfView:

[image]

Comment: I don't see the relationship between Tasks.Connect and the output.

Comment: @FrankHileman `Tasks.Connect` is just joining the two events together.  `EventSource` seems to take the name of the first joined method it finds and outputs that as a `task` in the manifest.  Therefore, there is one `task` for the two methods.  In combination with the `Opcode`s, this results in the PerfView event names of `/Connecting/Start` and `/Connecting/Stop`.  Both exist as events in the manifest, but are linked to a single task.